# Homogeneity of dimensions in an equation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

The principle of homogeneity of dimension states that "the dimension of all the terms in an equation must be identical" . But I'm confused that is this applicable both for vector or scalar equation in physics because for example we know that area under the velocity displacement curve is change in position, but area has the dimension  of [L]² and displacement has dimension of [L] - how are they equal?

Comment: The area under a curve does not necessarily have the units of area - think about how you're actually computing that "area"!

Comment: Isn't the area under the velocity vs  time curve the change in position (not the area under the velocity vs displacement curve)?

Answer (score 1):

The unit of area on a graph is determined by the units on the axes. For a velocity-time graph, the unit of area is are velocity x time = distance. For a pressure-volume graph, the unit of area is pressure x volume = force x distance = work or energy.